# How to print data of fortran unformatted file in python

Tags: python, scipy, fortran, temporary-files

[image: Fortran unformatted file]

I want to read Fortran unformatted file in python it contains variable like below
a,t,d,g,s,r,Re,pr,scsx,ex,sy,ey,sz,ez all of these are NxNxN
dimensional array except
first two that is a and t are integers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show that you have made some research, tried some things, and explain what didn't work for you. 
A tip: it all depends with which options the Fortran file has been written: default legacy mode or IOSTREAM mode? DIRECT or SEQUENTIAL access mode? Only the IOSTREAM files can be read in a straightward way from another langage. The other cases can be more or less complicated...

Comment: Are your NxNxN arrays real*4, real*8 or real*16.  Was the data generated on a different computer architecture than the one you are using to read it?  eg generated on a IBM mainframe and read on MacOS.

Comment: array of real*8 values, I have compiled the code using ifort and wish to read it using python in jupyter. However, I am free to read on any architecture so long as I can read the data.

         "open(311,file=Files, form='unformatted',status='new',iostat=s1,action='write')"
this is how I have written the file

Comment: Add `access='stream'`. After that you should be able to read the file from python the same way you would read any binary file containing integers and/or floating-points.